# How I can convert any Date to Los Angeles Time (PST) and then convert this one to Unix timestamp?

Tags: javascript, date, gettime

I'm trying to convert my local date or any local date to PST and then into timestamp. For example, this code works to convert the local time to PST:

```js
var offset = -7;
var result = new Date(new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000)
  .toUTCString()
  .replace(/ GMT$/, "");

console.log("Result:", result);
```

This one return the PST corresponding time, **but when I trying to apply the function getTime() (ex: result.getTime(); )** to convert this one on a Unix timestamp, I'm getting an error.

Comment: The error was "getTime is not a function", but please review my Answer at bottom, I founded a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
var offset = -7;
var result = new Date(new Date().getTime() + offset * 3600 * 1000)
  .toUTCString()
  .replace(/ GMT$/, "");

var unixTimestamp = new Date(result); // Result is converted to PST time.

console.log("Result:", Math.floor( unixTimestamp.getTime() / 1000 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [Luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon).

https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/?id=luxon

As easy as:

```bash
npm install luxon
```

And then

```
const { DateTime, IANAZone } = require('luxon') ;

function getEpochTimeInDesiredZone( tmStr , unit = 'ms', tzName = 'America/Los_Angeles' ) {
  const tz     = new IANAZone(tzName);
  const errMsg = unit !== 's' && unit !== 'ms'
                     ? `Invalid Unit: '${unit}': must be 's' or 'ms'`
                     : !zone.isValid
                     ? `Invalid TimeZone Name: '${tz}': must be a valid IANA time zone name`
                     : undefined
                     ;

  if (errMsg) { throw new Error(errMsg); }

  const dt = ( tmStr
               ? DateTime.fromISO( tmStr )
               : DateTime.now()
             )
             .setZone( tz )
             ;

  let epochTime = unit == 'ms' ? dt.toMillis() : dt.ToUnixSeconds() ;
  return epochTime;
}
```